# If particular cell is NOT BLANK copy down FORMULA from above cell

Tags: conditional-formatting

Basically I have the following formulas:

Column J: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,CCG,1,FALSE)),"Out of Area",VLOOKUP(I2,CCG,1,FALSE))

Column K: =INDEX(ResponsibleAgency,MATCH(N3,LeftLookup,0),MATCH(J3,TopLookup,0))

Column L: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(N3,PPLookup,2,FALSE)),"Missing F Code",VLOOKUP(N3,PPLookup,2,FALSE))

Column M: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(N3,PPLookup,3,FALSE))," ",VLOOKUP(N3,PPLookup,3,FALSE))

Basically, I only want these formulas to activiate provided that column A is populated with a date.  If there is no date in column A, I want the cells to remain blank.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, it is not possible to tell if cell contains a date or not in strict sense.

In Excel dates are in fact numbers representing number of days since January 1, 1900. I.e. today is `42066`. It's the **formatting** that makes those numbers look like dates to user. If you pass a cell containing a date to any formula, it receives this number.

As a workaround, you can check if the cell satisfies two conditions:

1. It is a number.
2. It falls into some date range that makes sense.

For example, if your column contains goods delivery dates you usually don't expect them be previous century or 50 years into the future.

So you can wrap your formulae into something like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(AND(A1>=DATE(2014,1,1),A1<=DATE(2015,12,13)),[LOGIC_IF_CORRECT_DATE_HERE],""),"")
```

Being said, it's still a workaround.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this way:

Comment: IF call A is NOT BLANK then apply formula?

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote my answer then. Welcome to StackOverflow!